# How to get grandparent directory with PHP

Tags: php

I have a following directory structure.

```
-webshop
   -controllers
      -webshop.php
```

In webshop.php I want to get webshop which is the grandparent of this file.

If I use the following I think I get 'controllers'.

```
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__)); // this will get controllers
```

How can I get the grandparent directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dirname works on directories as well, so you can get the parent of the parent and then use basename to get the base

```
basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

and test output

```
foo@bar: /tmp/a/b/c > pwd
/tmp/a/b/c
foo@bar: /tmp/a/b/c > cat test.php 
<?php
echo basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

foo@bar: /tmp/a/b/c > php test.php 
b
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be also done by:

```
echo basename(dirname(__DIR__, 2));
```

---

NOTE: THIS IS POSSIBLE ONLY IN PHP >= 7.0
The numeric count of directory levels to go up is an added functionality to `dirname` which is new feature in PHP 7. PHP5 did not have such functionality implemented.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: *Why* only in PHP => 7 ?

Comment: This is new feature in PHP 7. PHP5 does not have such function implemented. It was already great time to get this improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..');
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo basename(__DIR__. "/../..");` If I remember correctly.

PHP documentation:

> `__DIR__`    The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

Comment: Why `basename()` and not `realpath()`?